# Add DataBinding to Model in DataTriggers

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, templating

I have an `ObservableCollection<MyClass>`. And `MyClass` has a property called `IsColored`

I created a ListView, which should will color all the rows who have the property IsColored to true.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyClassList}">
    <hControls:ListView.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ListView">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
        </Style>
    </hControls:ListView.Style>

...

</ListView>
```

To satisfy the condition of Colors to my ListView I should add a DataTrigger

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsColored" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

But the problem is that IsColored is not recognized.

How can add a Binding to that property so I can access to it from the DataTrigger ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why @Anatoliy gave up so quickly and deleted his answer, because he was right... you *do* need to use a `DataTrigger`:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsColored}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

You commented to say that you got this error when trying this code:

> Cannot resolve property 'IsColored' in data context of type MyNameSpace.MyUserControl

This just means that your `Style` does not have access to the items of the `ListView`. Looking at your code, it seems as though you are trying to define a `Style` for a `ListViewItem`, but within a `ListView Style`. Instead, you need to use the [`ListView.ItemContainerStyle` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to apply the `Style` to the individual items. Try this instead:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyClassList}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsColored}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>    
    ...    
</ListView>
```

Comment: +1: I immediately not noticed his message in comment about error, so I removed the answer =).

Answer (score 0):

In first case you using the regular `Style.Trigger`, the `DataTrigger` using like this:

```
<DataTrigger Bindind="{Binding Path=IsColored}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
</DataTrigger>
```

About this error:

> Cannot resolve property 'IsColored' in data context of type MyNameSpace.MyUserControl

It tells, what you don't correctly setting the `DataContext`.

Comment: It doesn't work. It says : <Cannot resolve property 'IsColored' in data context of type MyNameSpace.MyUserControl>